# TABLE_DATE_RANGE assumes wrong table's amount with monthly tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I've searched for an appropriate channel to publish this issue before asking here, but unfortunately do not found any.

The problem:
[image]

My tables are saved as follows:

- dataset.table20120101
- dataset.table20120201
- dataset.table20120301
- [...]
- dataset.table20130101
- [...]
- dataset.table20140101
- [...]
- dataset.table20150101
- [...]
- dataset.table20160101
- dataset.table20160201

The above It's just an example, but the amount is up to 50, and today I already run queries which process much more than that.

On the UI we do not have a "Feedback" link/button, so, sorry again about opening a kind of github project issue here.

Comment: FYI, if you're looking for a place to report bugs/issues, you can do that on our [external issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues)

Comment: The back-end is calculating the number of tables assuming that I have daily tables, trying to prevent an overload.
I am saying specifically the "back-end" because I already tried to run the job using the python api client

Comment: Sorry then... I will open an issue there. Thanks @DannyKitt! :)

Comment: Sorry if that came across with a harsh tone - I think both here and there can be reasonable for this issue, but wanted to point it out based on the comment in your last paragraph.

Comment: No worries, my bad @DannyKitt. I will open a issue on the issue tracker and link it here. Thanks again! :)

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=461